# Difference between fields_for syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any difference between:

```
<%= event_form.fields_for :client, @client do |client| %>
```

and

```
<%= fields_for @event, :client, @client do |client| %>
```

The parent form looks like this:

```
<% form_for @event do |event_form| %>
```

Comment: Does the second example even work? I've never seen it written like that.

Comment: I support you @theIV, even I don't think that the second example might work. @Nate, instead of using <%= fields_for @event, :client, @client do |client| %> I think you must consider using this <%= fields_for :client do |c| %>, if you have accepts_nested_attributes_for :clients in your Event model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read from the docs (http://bit.ly/bMTJ5B), the first version

```
<%= event_form.fields_for :client, @client do |client| %>
```

is used in conjunction with accepts_nested_attributes_for :client and the update / create actions consider the event -> client association.

The second example:

```
<%= fields_for :client, @client do |client| %>
```

is the more general case when you need to specify additional models in the same form (see 'Generic Examples' section in the link I provided above. I think the correct form though is to leave out the @event param.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I should have known that I had *too much* syntax.